# Select multiple dataframes and make a list using loop

Tags: r, list, loops

This question might be silly. But I'm new to R and need help. I have over 500 data-frames. I would like to somehow select all of it using loop. 
My dataframes are named `T1, T2, T3, ..., T500`

For example, intuitively, something like I would want something like `list(T1:T500)` to work. instead of typing all the dataframes.

I tried

```
B<-NULL
for (i in 1:500) {
  A<-get((paste("T",i,sep="")))
  B<-list(B, A)
}
```

By this loop, I get a list of 2 elements where element [[1]] is like

`[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]]`

seems like I made a list in a list in a list in a list?

What have I done wrong? How can I get a list with 500 elements?

Comment: Would be safer to do this inside the loop: `B[[i]] <- A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mget` with `paste` to return a `list` of 'data.frame's.

```
lst <- mget(paste0("T", 1:500))
```